# What are idle processes in php-fpm?

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I'm using nginx with php-fpm at Centos.

Whenever I check `service php-fpm status`
I get idle processes count 30+. When I see it in detail using `service php-fpm status -l`, I see some processes which were thrown as exceptions.

I'm curious to know what these idle processes are and are these processes blocking server resources or not?

Answer (score 0):

Idle processes represent:

> The number of php-fpm processes that are idle, meaning already created in the pool and ready, waiting to handle requests.

Active processes:

> Number of active php-fpm processes which are currently active, and busy handling requests.

See here: [how to setup a php-fpm status page](https://www.icdsoft.com/en/kb/view/2053_php_fpm_status).

You can control the availability of these processes and how they run, By modifying php-fpm configuration.

there are three process management types:

1. **static**
2. **dynamic**
3. **ondemand**

you can configure the number of available process by modifying:

```
pm.max_children = 10
```

If your using `pm = static` the value will mean there will be 10 processes created and waiting for requests at all time.

If your using `pm = ondemand` the value will mean the max amount of child process that can be created are 10 and they will be created on demand.

Learn more about the different types and choose whats right for you:
[PHP-FPM Tuning](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/an-introduction-to-php-fpm-tuning)